# Typedefed array type is not assignable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

I am trying to build a simple VM. I have an array which represents it's memory (an array of `uint8_t`). To be more expressive I `typedef` an array of `uint8_t`:

```
typedef uint8_t chip8_memory[0xfff];
```

I pass this array as a reference around my codebase:

```
void chip8_2nnn(const chip8_opcode oc, chip8_cpu_state* cs, chip8_memory* m) {
    m[cs->sp]     = cs->pc & 0xff;
    m[cs->sp + 1] = cs->pc >> 8;
    cs->sp -= 2;
    cs->pc = nnn(oc);
}
```

The above function generates the following error:

```
chip8.c:41:17: error: array type 'chip8_memory' (aka 'uint8_t [4095]') is not assignable
  m[cs->sp]     = cs->pc & 0xff;
  ~~~~~~~~~     ^
chip8.c:42:17: error: array type 'chip8_memory' (aka 'uint8_t [4095]') is not assignable
  m[cs->sp + 1] = cs->pc >> 8;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
2 errors generated.
```

The minimal failing example:

```
TEST(foo, bar) {
    typedef int foo[3];
    foo  bar = {1, 2, 3};
    foo* baz = &bar;

    bar[2] = 5;
    baz[2] = 5;
}
```

What would be the best approach to solve this issue? I want a type name which shows that it is not just an array, but the memory. And also I want to pass it around code base and read/modify it's values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It would be (the correct way to access would be)

```
(*m)[cs->sp]     = cs->pc & 0xff;
```

As pointer to an array is of type `uint8_t (*)[]` (this is what is the type for `m`). So you need to dereference it before accessing its elements.

Also here if you have simply used `chip8_memory m` as parameter to the function then you could have accessed it the way you did - provided you passed as an argument the array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, indeed, `chip8_memory m` in declaration solves my issue. And it is nice :)

I think both answers provided to this question are correct. I am not sure which one to accept... There should be merge answers button here...

Comment: @x7_.: All the best

Answer (score 1):

The type `chip8_memory*` is a *pointer* to the array, it's not the array itself. The type of `chip8_memory*` is `uint8_t (*)[0xfff]`.

That means `m[any_index]` is an `chip8_memory` array. And that the only possible way to use `m` (with the current declaration) is like `m[0][cs->sp]` or `(*m)[cs->sp]`.

Solution? Don't make `m` a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This does answer my question. I should not have declared `m` as a pointer. As mentioned in the other answer, I find both answers helpful and correct. Not sure which one to accept...